# Polymer fails to load in iOS10 but not iOS9

Tags: polymer, aurelia

I have an Aurelia app running in phonegap and it works fine on ios9+ but on ios10+ it fails to load Polymer.

When the Aurelia polymer plugin checks to see if Polymer is on the window object it is null.

I am loading webcomponents-lite.js and it is initializing properly.

Not sure where to look
Michael

Comment: It could be related to missing polyfills, checkout what the plugin needs and make sure those polyfills are applied

Comment: I am loading the webcomponentsjs polyfill which is all I needed prior to iOS10. I updated the Aurelia-plugin to the latest version and it now displays an error Polymer not loaded. The plugin is checking for Polymer on the window when it displays this error. So now all signs point to Polymer issues on iOS10

Answer (score 0):

try to load webcomponents-lite.js instead of webcomponents.js

Comment: that didn't help